# Client certificate time out in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, client-certificates, x509certificate2, mmc

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"Certificate/certificate.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    
   var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
   handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
   handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11;
   handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
   var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    
    
   var request = new HttpRequestMessage
       {
         Method = method,
         RequestUri = new Uri("endpoint" + url, UriKind.Absolute),
         Content = content
       };
   var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
   var responseStr = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This method works in the local environment but when I publish this to the AWS ec2 env, I get this error **A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**.

I have also added client certificate to the current user and local machine in ec2 using mmc.

Running OS in ec2 windows server 2019 Datacenter (Build 17763).

Comment: Looks like it's nothign to do with the certificate, the server is just not responding. What sort of Uri starts `endpoint` it doesn't look valid? Also why set `SslProtocols` manually, are you sure you want insecure protocols? You are also missing `using` on various objects

Comment: I set SslProtocols to auto in my local env but that threw an error thats why I set it manual

Comment: And you are sure the server is responding? Can you ping it? Can you open that URL in a browser or in Postman?

Comment: Yes, I used postman and it works fine. Also can you elaborate on the using objects im missing

Comment: Well your URL doesn't look right as I said. You need to do `using var handler` and `using var client` and `using var request` and `using var result` etc

Comment: thanks for your time, buddy. i figure it out its was issue in ec2 server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by ec2 instance server configuration.
After i change security groups inbound and outbound rules to below settings it worked fine.

**Inbound rule**

- IPv4 All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP    All 0.0.0.0/0
- IPv4 All TCP TCP 0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0
- IPv4 RDP TCP 3389    0.0.0.0/0
- IPv4 HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
- IPv4 HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0

**Outbound rule**

- IPv4 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
- IPv4 All TCP TCP 0 - 65535   0.0.0.0/0
- IPv4 All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP    All